# Decoding Equivalence Relations

Tags: equivalence-relations, formal-grammar

Working on a problem set in which I need to evaluate a set of relations for transitiveness, symmetry, and reflexiveness. Intuitive relations seem graspable but more difficult relations just seem untouchable to me and I don't even know where to begin. In short, I'm in need of some help learning how to decode more complex relations.

A brief and simple example to make sure I'm going about this the right way:

R= To be adjacent

Reflexive (a~a): No -- X cannot be adjacent of itself

Symmetric (a~b): Yes -- X can be adjacent to Y

Transitive (a~b,b~c, therefore a~c): No -- If X is adjacent left to Y and Y is adjacent left of Z, X and Z are not adjacent

**More problematic relations:**

Edit: I've noticed the intuitive problem here for me is that these relations aren't simple predicates like taller, loves, bigger. Instead, the relation itself seems more like a~b from the get-go contingent on two things meeting certain criteria.

1. the relation defined on pairs of integers that holds just in case both integers are even.

In this case, my confusion lies in whether each variable is a *pair of integers* or a *single* integer. If it is a pair how do we even test these for symmetry or transitiveness? If its a single integer how can it possibly have the relation of being a pair of two even integers?

2. the relation defined on natural numbers of having a common factor greater than 3

Again whats our domain? If it's all natural numbers any number that doesnt have 3 as a factor is a counter-example of reflexiveness. If it is just numbers with 3 as a factor then how do we test for symmetry? How are we to relate two numbers a~b when the relation itself is a a~b (natural numbers who have a *common* factor greater than 3) relation.

Comment: First half of your post, yes you seem to have the right idea of the "is adjacent" relation for general graphs, however I will point out that it does depend on what graph you are referring to.  The complete multigraph with loops you do in fact have every vertex is adjacent to every other vertex including itself.  As for the next two examples the phrase "*just in [the] case both integers are even*" implies to me that we are looking at the relation where one integer is related to another iff both are even.  I.e. the domain and codomain are both $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Testing symmetry or transitiveness, if $a\sim b$ that implies that both $a$ and $b$ are even integers.  That implies then that $b\sim a$ since they continue to be even integers, so it is symmetric.  Transitivity can be explained the same way.  As for the next example, it sounds like it is indeed defined on all naturals, so $1$ is not related to anything as it shares no factors other than $1$.  We say here $a\sim b\iff \gcd(a,b)>3$.  It is symmetric since $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,a)$, but it is not necessarily transitive.  $7\sim 28$ and $28\sim 4$ but $\gcd(7,4)=1$

Comment: "More problematic relations": Why ? John is taller than Jim is exactly like $3 > 2$.

Comment: "my confusion lies in whether each variable is a pair of integers or a single integer" A *relation* can be binary (taller, less than), ternary (x lies between y and z) and more. More "natural" relations are *binary*. A *unary* relation is a "degenerate" case: a predicate or property, like odd and even: $2$ is even while $3$ is odd. They "involve" a single element each time.

Comment: "the relation defined on natural numbers of having a common factor greater than 3" is defined on the set $\mathbb N$ of *naturals*. We have that $nRm \text { iff } \exists k  \ \exists l_1 \ \exists l_2 \ (n=k \times l_1 \text { and } m=k \times l_2 \text { and } k > 3 )$. As you can see, we have a condition to be checked for every pair $(n,m)$ of numbers; for some it holds: e.g. $n=18$ and $m=24$ (they have the common factor $6$), while for other pairs it does not: $n=3$ and $m=5$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to assume that these relations are being defined on all integers.  But it should say that somewhere
1)

a~b if a and b are both even numbers

Symmetry
a~a -- not if a is an odd number
Reflexive and transitive hold

2) a~b if $\gcd(a,b) > 3$
Symmetry
not if $|a|<3$

Reflexive holds.

Transitivity

let $a = 5, b = 20, c = 4$

a ~ b, b~c but not a~c